# Open ionic modal via route with angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I have a modal and I want it to present when the user navigates to specific route.

I currently have a button and as soon as the user clicks on it the model is presented but the route obviously does not change.

The behavior I want to achieve is that when the user clicks the button it navigates to child route and only the modal is opening, the component doesn't re-render.

For example:

I have list of entities at '/entities'
When the user clicks on one of them it only opens a modal at '/entities/:entityId' on the same component.
Furthermore, when the user enters '/entities/:entityId' the corresponding  modal will open.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd also like to be able to implement this functionality...

Comment: https://tanpure-anjali.medium.com/dynamic-modals-with-separate-url-address-c8bda1709077